# Initiating a phone call using my app in Android

Tags: android

Lets assume you have installed Viber or skype in your phone. When you call (just taking general call from your phone) you dial number and press dial button will pop up a selction pop up by listing viber and skype. That means your call can be redirected to that.

I need the same thing to be done. I need that call to be intercepted

Comment: Your question isn't really phrased correctly for SO.  Look into "intent filters," I think.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 2):

I thing you want this type of output:
[image]

means in your application, you clicked button for calling someone, it display this type of popup of app, which can be used as dialer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes thats correct but I need the number that dialed by using that native dial pad??in here its hardcorded?

Comment: When call button press it opens the dial pad and when press call ..I need my app listed in selector and it should receive diled number..